# Create controls during runtime and access their values

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create CheckedListBox's at runtime from the data that is in a database table.

Data in the table for example

```
Kern
Formax
Buhrs
```

for each row in the table I want the code to create a new CheckedListBox with a name of the row.

After the creating of the CheckedListBox I want to populate it from another table containing other data.

As soon as the client is done with the data selection in the CheckedListBox's I want to read all the checked values in the CheckedListBox's and save it into an array.

My trouble comes with creating the CheckedListBox's and accessing the data as soon as the client clicks done.

I'm very new to creating controls at runtime.

Thanks in advance:)

I have solved this by creating an array of checkedlistboxs, and by creating each checkedlistbox with the ammount of rows in my table, and by populating the checkedlistboxs with the data in the table. By itterating through all pf the checkedlistboxs i get all of the values that is checked and store them into another table.

```
private CheckedListBox[] Machines;

Machines = new CheckedListBox[test.Length];
int iLocation = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < Machines.Length; i++)
        {
            Machines[i] = new CheckedListBox();
            Machines[i].Name = "clb" + test[i].ToString();

            Machines[i].Location = new Point(iLocation, 6);
            Machines[i].Size = new Size(120, 139);

            iLocation += Machines[i].Width + 6;


            this.Controls.Add(Machines[i]);
        }
        Machines[2].Items.Add("Hello");
        Machines[2].Items.Add("Goodbye");
```

This code is for accessing data in the checked list box

```
ArrayList arrCheckedItems = new ArrayList();
        CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection objCheckedItem = Machines[2].CheckedItems;
        for (int i = 0; i < objCheckedItem.Count; i++)
        {

            arrCheckedItems.Add(objCheckedItem[i]);
        }
        string[] srtArray = arrCheckedItems.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.String")) as string[];
        int iMachines = srtArray.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < iMachines; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(srtArray[i].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: You should probably post some code to see what you have tried.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but a WinForm (like WPF) has 2 files for each window. One is the (partial) 'code class', which contains your logic, the other the (partial) 'layout class', which contains the controls. You can open both in code view (though the layout class is usually WYSIWYG) by right clicking the file and clicking the menu-option. The 'layout class' has all the controls in 'code form', which you can just copy and use during runtime to create your own components. (You can use this to get familiar with creating components at runtime.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand this correctly, you have 2 types of entities ... lets call them T1 and T2

now you want to add one control to your form for every T1 entity that enables you to associate T2 entities to T1 entities, and that control should be a CheckedListBox ...

well, here is a quick and dirty example form that does this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace controlsAtRuntime
{

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FlowLayoutPanel mainPanel;
        private Button button1;
        private Button button2;
        private Button button3;

        MyDataClass1[] T1Items = new MyDataClass1[] { new MyDataClass1 { Name = "I am element 1" }, new MyDataClass1 { Name = "I am element 2" } };
        MyDataClass2[] T2Items = new MyDataClass2[] { new MyDataClass2 { Name = "Foo" }, new MyDataClass2 { Name = "Bar" } };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void setUpControlsAtRuntime()
        {
            mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
            foreach (var item in T1Items)
            {
                mainPanel.Controls.Add(getControlForT1Entity(item, T2Items));
            }
        }

        private GroupBox getControlForT1Entity(MyDataClass1 entity,IEnumerable<MyDataClass2> asscociatableData)
        {
            GroupBox box = new GroupBox();//outer element that can give our checked list box a visible name
            box.Text = entity.Name;
            box.Tag = entity; // so you can know the entity this box belongs to ...
            box.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            box.AutoSize = true;
            CheckedListBox chklb = new CheckedListBox();
            foreach (var item in asscociatableData)
            { 
                chklb.Items.Add(item, entity.associatedData != null && entity.associatedData.Contains(item));
                //add all items, and check them if they were contained in entity.associatedData
            }
            box.Controls.Add(chklb);
            chklb.Location = new Point(10, 20);
            return box;
        }

        private IEnumerable<MyDataClass2> getCheckedItemsFromOuterBox(GroupBox box)
        { 
            var chklb = box.Controls[0] as CheckedListBox;
            if (chklb != null)
            { 
                return chklb.CheckedItems.OfType<MyDataClass2>();
            }
            throw new Exception("whoops... that was none of the expected GroupBox Controls...");
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.mainPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // mainPanel
            // 
            this.mainPanel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.mainPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.mainPanel.Name = "mainPanel";
            this.mainPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(417, 269);
            this.mainPanel.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(330, 287);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "save selection";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 287);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "clear panel";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 287);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button3.Text = "setup panel";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(441, 322);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.mainPanel);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in mainPanel.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().Where(x=>x.Tag is MyDataClass1))
            {
                var entity = item.Tag as MyDataClass1;
                entity.associatedData = getCheckedItemsFromOuterBox(item);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setUpControlsAtRuntime();
        }
    }
    public class MyDataClass1
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MyDataClass2> associatedData { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyDataClass2
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```